# OSX ImageMagick no decode delegate for this image format `PNG'

Tags: macos, delegates, imagemagick, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I am getting the following error when trying to run imagemagick commands on a PNG:

```
$ identify image.png
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
```

As a matter of fact, I am getting the same on a JPEG as well.

My system details:
ImageMagick is installed on MacOS Big Sur with Homebrew:

```
$ brew info imagemagick
imagemagick: stable 7.1.0-5 (bottled), HEAD
Tools and libraries to manipulate images in many formats
https://www.imagemagick.org/
/opt/brew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.0-5 (799 files, 30MB) *
  Built from source on 2021-08-24 at 11:25:21
```

It seems like the delegates are properly listed:

```
$ identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-5 Q16 x86_64 2021-08-22 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(5.0)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png tiff webp xml zlib
```

and here, taken from the `delegates.xml` list I assume:

```
$ magick -list delegate | grep png
    blender =>          "blender' -b '%i' -F PNG -o '%o''\n'magick' convert -concatenate '%o*.png' '%o"
        bpg =>          "bpgdec' -b 16 -o '%o.png' '%i'; /bin/mv '%o.png' '%o"
 dng:decode =>          "ufraw-batch' --silent --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16 '--output=%u.png' '%i"
        png<= webp      "cwebp' -quiet %Q '%i' -o '%o"
        png<= bpg       "bpgenc' -b 12 -q '%~' -o '%o' '%i"
    blender =>          "blender' -b '%i' -F PNG -o '%o''\n'magick' convert -concatenate '%o*.png' '%o"
        bpg =>          "bpgdec' -b 16 -o '%o.png' '%i'; /bin/mv '%o.png' '%o"
 dng:decode =>          "ufraw-batch' --silent --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16 '--output=%u.png' '%i"
        png<= bpg       "bpgenc' -b 12 -q '%~' -o '%o' '%i"
        png<= webp      "cwebp' -quiet %Q '%i' -o '%o"
```

I do have `libpng` and `webp` installed through homebrew...

Yet somehow, I am not able to run `convert` (or `identify`) on any PNG (nor JPEG... probably same with other image types too). I assume something might be wrong with how IM is linked against the delegate libraries? But I am totally out of ideas on what to check...

Also, this returns an empty list - I am not sure if this is supposed to be the case:

```
$ convert -list format
```

Comment: It would seem you installed from source. You are then responsible to install all needed delegate libraries. You should install from a binary that comes with the delegates.

Comment: I did have the delegates installed, but for some reason IM did not realize that all the coders are there... not sure why during build / configuration the env var wasn't set properly. Check the answer I posted below. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Figured out what the issue was... for some reason, debugging `identify` with `identify -debug module`, we see that IM can not find the decoder modules...

```
$ identify -debug module image.png
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/OpenModule/1273/Module
  Searching for module "PNG" using filename "png.la"
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/546/Module
  Searching for coder module file "png.la" ...
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/OpenModule/1273/Module
  Searching for module "PNG" using filename "png.la"
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/546/Module
  Searching for coder module file "png.la" ...
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/OpenModule/1273/Module
  Searching for module "PNG" using filename "png.la"
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/546/Module
  Searching for coder module file "png.la" ...
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/OpenModule/1273/Module
  Searching for module "PNG" using filename "png.la"
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/546/Module
  Searching for coder module file "png.la" ...
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/OpenModule/1273/Module
  Searching for module "PNG" using filename "png.la"
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/546/Module
  Searching for coder module file "png.la" ...
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/OpenModule/1273/Module
  Searching for module "PNG" using filename "png.la"
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/546/Module
  Searching for coder module file "png.la" ...
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/OpenModule/1273/Module
  Searching for module "PNG" using filename "png.la"
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/546/Module
  Searching for coder module file "png.la" ...
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/OpenModule/1273/Module
  Searching for module "PNG" using filename "png.la"
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/546/Module
  Searching for coder module file "png.la" ...
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/OpenModule/1273/Module
  Searching for module "PNG" using filename "png.la"
2021-08-24T23:43:18+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Module identify[10123]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/546/Module
  Searching for coder module file "png.la" ...
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
```

After noticing this, I set the proper path to the coder modules through the env var:

```
export MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH="$(brew --prefix)/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.0-5/lib/ImageMagick/modules-Q16HDRI/coders"
```